# How to count average messages for 15 sec interval from date in sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables that looks a bit like this.

PersonTable

| ID | Person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |

TypeToPersonTable

| SPECID | PersonID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 |

RequestDateTable

| ID | SPECID | rDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 02-FEB-20 |
| 2 | 3 | 02-FEB-20 |
| 3 | 3 | 02-FEB-20 |
| 4 | 7 | 02-FEB-20 |
| 5 | 7 | 02-FEB-20 |

I need to calculate how many requests sends each person on average every 15 seconds and group it by hour. So the result has to look like this.

| person | hourPeriod | requests in interval count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | from 15 to 16 | 2,83 |
| name1 | from 10 to 11 | 0,05 |
| name2 | from 15 to 16 | 3,39 |

I started with something like this but now i'm completely stuck.

```
SELECT PersonTable.Perosn AS person, 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(RequestDateTable.rDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS hourPeriod,
    COUNT(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CAST(RequestDateTable.rDATE AS TIMESTAMP))) AS "requests in interval count"
FROM   PersonTable
JOIN TypeToPersonTable ON PersonTable.ID = TypeToPersonTable.PersonID
JOIN RequestDateTable ON RequestDateTable.SPECID = TypeToPersonTable.SPECID
GROUP BY PersonTable.Person, RequestDateTable.rDATE
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but what field is used to store hours? Is there a logic behind to create group of hours: 'from ...  to ...'?

Comment: I need to extract hours and seconds from column rDate. So i can see average count of requests per 15 second in each hour. I'm sorry if this is confusing. This is confusing for me too.

Comment: In your example data `rDate` field does not contain time part :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear but it seems like you need to segment hours into 15 seconds intervals. There are 240 (60 min * 4) 15 second intervals. Then, I guess, you want to count the requests within an hour and calculate average number of requests per either total number of segments in hour (240) or per number of segments within an hour that requests were done at. Hope this could help you solve your problem.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    persons (ID, PERSON) AS
        (   Select 1, 'Name 1' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'Name 2' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'Name 3' From Dual 
        ),
    types_to_persons (SPEC_ID, PERSON_ID) AS
        (   Select 3, 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 7, 2 From Dual Union All
            Select 9, 3 From Dual 
        ),
    request_dates (ID, SPEC_ID, R_DATE) AS
        (   Select 1, 3, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 3) * (LEVEL + 1) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 20 Union All
      Select 2, 3, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 3) * (LEVEL + 2) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 21 Union All
      Select 3, 3, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:45:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 13) * (LEVEL + 2) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 22 Union All
      Select 4, 7, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 13) * (LEVEL + 2) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 23 Union All
      Select 5, 7, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 3) * (LEVEL + 2) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 24 Union All
      Select 5, 7, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:30:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 3) * (LEVEL + 3) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 25 Union All
      Select 6, 9, To_Date('02-FEB-2020 15:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (LEVEL * 13) * (LEVEL + 1) * (1 / 86400) From Dual Connect By Level <= 30 
        ),
```

There are 165 request_dates in sample data. The data should be prepared for the aggregation so I created a cte (named it segments). The cte extracts the time elements from R_DATE and calculate the 15 sec segment number within each hour.

```sql
  segments AS
    ( Select  
            p.ID, p.PERSON, t.SPEC_ID, 
            TRUNC(r.R_DATE) "R_DATE",
            To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') "R_TIME",
            --
            To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'hh24')) "R_HOUR",
            To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'mi')) "R_MINUTE",
            To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'ss')) "R_SECOND",
            --
            (To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'mi')) * 4) + CASE WHEN To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'ss')) <= 15 THEN 1
                                                            WHEN To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'ss')) <= 30 THEN 2 
                                                            WHEN To_Number(To_Char(r.R_DATE, 'ss')) <= 45 THEN 3
                                                       ELSE 4 
                                                       END "HOUR_SEGMENT",
            --
            Min(EXTRACT(Hour From CAST(r.R_DATE as TIMESTAMP))) OVER(Partition By p.PERSON, R_DATE) "HOUR_START",
            Max(EXTRACT(Hour From CAST(r.R_DATE as TIMESTAMP))) OVER(Partition By p.PERSON, R_DATE) + 1 "HOUR_END"
      From        persons p
      Inner Join  types_to_persons t ON(p.ID = t.PERSON_ID)
      Inner Join  request_dates r ON(r.SPEC_ID = t.SPEC_ID)
      Order By    p.PERSON
    )
-- the result has 165 rows like below
-- segments cte result:
        ID PERSON    SPEC_ID R_DATE    R_TIME       R_HOUR   R_MINUTE   R_SECOND HOUR_SEGMENT HOUR_START   HOUR_END
---------- ------ ---------- --------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
         1 Name 1          3 02-FEB-20 15:00:06         15          0          6            1         15         16 
         1 Name 1          3 02-FEB-20 15:00:09         15          0          9            1         15         16 
         1 Name 1          3 02-FEB-20 15:00:18         15          0         18            2         15         16 
         1 Name 1          3 02-FEB-20 15:00:24         15          0         24            2         15         16 
         1 Name 1          3 02-FEB-20 15:00:36         15          0         36            3         15         16
... ... ...
         3 Name 3          9 02-FEB-20 17:43:48         17         43         48          176         17         18 
         3 Name 3          9 02-FEB-20 17:55:56         17         55         56          224         17         18 
         3 Name 3          9 02-FEB-20 18:08:30         18          8         30           34         18         19 
         3 Name 3          9 02-FEB-20 18:21:30         18         21         30           86         18         19
```

Now you can get different calculations/aggregations using the segmented data from above.
Main SQL

```sql
Select    PERSON, R_DATE, 
          LPAD(HOUR_START, 2, '0') || '-' || LPAD(HOUR_END, 2, '0') "HOUR_RANGE",
          R_HOUR,
          Count(*) "REQUESTS", Count(DISTINCT HOUR_SEGMENT) "R_SEGMENTS", 
          Round(Count(*) / Count(DISTINCT HOUR_SEGMENT), 2) "AVG_PER_R_SEGMENT",
          60 * 4 "TOTAL_SEGMENTS",
          Round(Count(*) / 240, 2) "AVG_PER_HOUR_SEGMENTED"
From      segments
Group By  PERSON, R_DATE, R_HOUR, LPAD(HOUR_START, 2, '0') || '-' || LPAD(HOUR_END, 2, '0')
Order By  PERSON, R_DATE, R_HOUR, LPAD(HOUR_START, 2, '0') || '-' || LPAD(HOUR_END, 2, '0')

R e s u l t :
PERSON R_DATE    HOUR_RANGE     R_HOUR   REQUESTS R_SEGMENTS AVG_PER_R_SEGMENT TOTAL_SEGMENTS AVG_PER_HOUR_SEGMENTED
------ --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------- -------------- ----------------------
Name 1 02-FEB-20 15-16              15         48         44              1.09            240                     .2 
Name 1 02-FEB-20 16-17              16         10         10                 1            240                    .04 
Name 1 02-FEB-20 17-18              17          5          5                 1            240                    .02 
Name 2 02-FEB-20 15-16              15         62         56              1.11            240                    .26 
Name 2 02-FEB-20 16-17              16          9          8              1.13            240                    .04 
Name 2 02-FEB-20 17-18              17          1          1                 1            240                      0 
Name 3 02-FEB-20 15-16              15         16         16                 1            240                    .07 
Name 3 02-FEB-20 16-17              16          7          7                 1            240                    .03 
Name 3 02-FEB-20 17-18              17          5          5                 1            240                    .02 
Name 3 02-FEB-20 18-19              18          2          2                 1            240                    .01
```